# A/C compressor connection to the house not sealed anymore. How do I fix it?

Tags: hvac, exterior

The A/C compressor that sits outside our home had a sealed connection to the house (pretty new, 3 years old), and it seems a "gasket" was created with silicone.  However, the soil underneath the compressor started to shift a bit, and so the compressor now sits slighly farther from the house.  We have fixed that, so it's not moving anymore, but now the A/C hoses connecting to the house look like this:

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

Should I simply put some duct tape around it to seal it again?  Should I remove the silicon and create a larger silicone gasket?  Not sure if this is a big deal, and we haven't seen any unwanted side effects, but I want to avoid any long-term problems.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the silicone pieces and trim the grey rubber back and then use Great Stuff to fill in the voids and insulate the pipes. You've got a pretty good opening there and you don't want any critters crawling in there.

Answer (score 1):

I would possibly use 1 layer of tape sticky side out then coat with silicone to fully seal. You really won’t have any real efficiency losses but that opening is large enough for rodents to enter, so I would want to seal it up for that reason.

I cases where I don’t want the tape to stick to things I will put it on sticky side out and over lap it on itself, then add some silicon to make a better covering that critters won’t chew on.